# How to put the fiddler composer window back after tear off?

Tags: fiddler

The "options" sub-tab of the fiddler "Composer" tab lets you tear off the Composer into a floating window.  Question is how to put it back?  I lost the floating window and now fiddler's composer is gone.  I didn't find anything in the menus to restore fiddler or its GUI to factory defaults. I tried uninstalling and reinstalling fiddler, no-go;  Then uninstalling, grepping the registry and blowing away all keys that had anything to do with fiddler and reinstalling -- no-go.  The only thing that worked was paving the machine -- (which I had to do anyway -- I didn't do that just to solve this fiddler problem!)

Comment: I found the answer to this here:
http://superuser.com/questions/460094/how-do-i-re-attach-the-details-window-in-fiddler-after-using-tearoff

Comment: Thanks!  Post as answer and I'll mark it so.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

The floated Details View can be returned to the docked state by closing it.

In your case, it sounds like the view may have gone off-screen. On Windows 7 with Fiddler 2.4.1.1, a floated Details View shows up in the taskbar as a distinct Fiddler window. Hovering over the Fiddler icon on the taskbar, moving the cursor over the Details View preview, right-clicking the Details View preview, selecting Maximize, and then pressing Alt-F4 returns the view to its docked state.

Obviously, flattening your box and reinstalling Fiddler is also a solution. ;)